# what happens if System Exception occurs from a method in a session bean in EJB 3.0?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0

What happens if a system exception occurs from a method in a session bean that has a transaction attribute REQUIRED_NEW and this method is called by some other method which is running in other transaction (i.e REQUIRED).

[image: Transaction]

Will the suspended transcation(i.e Required) rollback or not ??

Comment: Will the suspended transcation(i.e Required) rollback or not ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens if System Exception occurs from a method in a session bean in EJB 3.0?

This is what the ejb3 specification says:

> 14.2.2 System Exceptions
>
> ... The container catches a non-application exception; logs it; and, unless the bean is a message-driven bean, throws the javax.ejb.EJBException.
>
> ... The transaction in which the bean method participated will be rolled back....

and the bean instance will be discared.

> Will the suspended transcation(i.e Required) rollback or not ??

In your case the Client method runs in a different transactional context, therefore, if you catch the
`javax.ejb.EJBException` that was originated in the target bean, the transaction will commit. Otherwise, the transaction will be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't handle exception inside method A, exception will throw higher and rollback bought transactions.